# Spring Cloud Config resolve secret propertiers via Vault and Git

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I want to use this scheme. I have git repo with some config files, which contains secret props, eg. password. And I have Vault witch secrets.

I want the spring cloud server to go to the repository and take the properties, and then go through the secret properties and take their values from the vault.

Some property file in git:

```
endpoints:
  db:
    default-settings:
      credentials:
        login: test
        password: ${passwordInVault}
```

Value `passwordInVault` stored in Vault. Before giving it to the client, I want it to be replaced with the real value from the vault.

I didn't find anything like this in the documentation. Is it possible to implement this, is there a link where you can read about it?